# Not able to create custom reports in experience analytics

Tags: experience-analytics

We are trying to create custom analytics reports but are not able to show any data in charts.

Below are the steps followed to create a custom report,

1. Created custom dimensions and segments.
2. Created custom filter and added rule **where the interaction started at the Home** and attached filter to segment.
3. In core db, Added **ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart Parameters** under Audience **PageSettings** and added segments and metrics.
4. In Sitecore rocks,  Added Rendering **ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart** by right-clicking on Audience and adding data source as **ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart Parameters**.
5. Deployed created segment.
6. If we view the reports under `Audience`, custom reports are not showing any data other than the report title.

Please suggest to me if any configuration or steps are required to make the custom analytics report work.

Comment: You maybe need to turn on historical reaggregation to see "old data" in your report -> https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/analyzing_and_reporting/analytics/configuring/enable_historical_reaggregation or wait couple of minutes (By default, data collection starts 30 minutes after deployment.) for report to process your new data -> https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/analyzing_and_reporting/analytics/configuring/create_a_custom_report_filter_and_segment

Comment: thanks @PeterProchazka, even after doing above settings, I am not able to show data in custom chart. If I attach existing dimensions segment to custom char, we able to see the data, another thing what I noticed is, in build dimensions segments don't have filters attached to them. Is there registration required for custom dimensions.

Comment: @PeterProchazka please check the above  comment

Comment: For which version of Sitecore is this?

Comment: @PeterProchazka, this is for sitecore-9.0.1

Comment: I hope that I'm not late to this question. We had the same experience when we tried to extend some reports in the sitecore analytics. I briefly described it here [https://medium.com/@avsenev/create-your-first-custom-report-in-sitecore-8-1-5e76298ebaeb](https://medium.com/@avsenev/create-your-first-custom-report-in-sitecore-8-1-5e76298ebaeb)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your existing `dimensions and segments`, just add relevant `DimensionKeys` to the `chart` (e.g., for a pattern match, add patternCard item id to the key rendering properties, without braces and dashes), and you can see that data will appear in the chart. this trick worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely correct, additional configuration is needed in addition to what you have described, if your custom dimensions has any code associated with it. Create an include file or use an existing one, add into **<sitecore>** section the following (put into appropriate places your `dimension ID`, `full class name`, and `DLL` the class resides at):

```
    <experienceAnalytics>
      <aggregation>
        <patch:attribute name="enabled" value="true"/>
        <logger type="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Diagnostics.Logger, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core" singleInstance="true"/>
        <!-- This section hosts the definitions of the Experience Analytics dimensions
            'id' attribute is the unique identifier and should match the ID of the corresponding dimension definition item in Marketing Control Panel
            'type' attribute references the fully qualified class name and assembly name with the dimension implementation.
        -->
        <dimensions>
          <dimension id="[dimension item ID]" type="[full class reference], [DLL name]" />
        </dimensions>
      </aggregation>
    </experienceAnalytics>
```

This will serve as a **registration** of your custom dimension, and Sitecore will **pick up** on it.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the steps you've described, it seems like you have set up the necessary configurations for creating custom analytics reports in Sitecore Experience Analytics. However, if you're not seeing any data in the charts, there could be a few potential reasons and additional steps you can take to troubleshoot the issue:

- **Verify data availability:** Make sure that you have data available in
  Sitecore Experience Analytics for the specific custom dimensions,
  segments, and filters you have created. You can check this by
  manually inspecting the Experience Analytics dashboard or by running
  test interactions on your website to generate data.
- **Validate dimension and segment configuration:** Ensure that the custom
  dimensions and segments you created are correctly defined and
  populated with the appropriate data. Double-check the rules and
  filters attached to the segments to confirm that they match the
  intended criteria for data inclusion.
- **Check ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart Parameters configuration:** Review
  the configuration for ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart Parameters in the
  core database. Make sure you have correctly specified the segments
  and metrics you want to display in the chart. Verify that the segment
  names and metric keys are accurate and exist in your Sitecore
  instance.
- **Verify Sitecore Rocks setup:** Ensure that the rendering of the
  ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart in Sitecore Rocks is correctly
  configured. Double-check that you have set the data source as
  ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart Parameters and that it corresponds to
  the correct database and location within Sitecore.
- **Check deployment of segments:** Confirm that the custom segments have been properly deployed and are available for use in reporting.
  You can validate this by checking the segmentation conditions for
  individual contacts in the Experience Profile.
- **Check reporting timeframe:** Ensure that the reporting timeframe
  selected in Sitecore Experience Analytics includes the timeframe when
  the interactions matching your custom segments occurred. Adjust the
  date range to include the relevant data.
- **Verify user access rights:** Confirm that the user account you are
  using to access Sitecore Experience Analytics has the necessary
  permissions to view and analyze the data. Check the user roles and
  access rights in Sitecore to ensure that they include the required
  analytics permissions.

By carefully reviewing these steps and validating each configuration, you should be able to identify any potential issues and get your custom analytics reports to display the desired data in the charts.